# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 N:N LINQ query with where clause containing Guid

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have constructed a simple query to return a Users Team membership (N: N relationship).  This works fine for all users, however, when I add a where clause to restrict to a specific user it throws a fault exception (see stack trace below).

Strangely this works fine with "where Users.FullName.StartsWith("Alex")".  Does the Dynamics CRM SDK LINQ implementation not support Guides in where clauses?

Any advice?

**Example code**

```
 using (var service = new OrganizationService("Xrm"))
        {
            using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
            {
                var AlexUser = xrm.SystemUserSet.Where(p => p.FullName.StartsWith("Alex")).First();
                var AlexID = AlexUser.Id;

                var Test =
                        from Users in xrm.SystemUserSet
                        join TeamMemberships in xrm.TeamMembershipSet on Users.Id equals TeamMemberships.SystemUserId
                        join Teams in xrm.TeamSet on TeamMemberships.TeamId equals Teams.Id
                        where Users.Id == AlexID     // <-- problematic where clause
                        orderby Users.FullName
                        select new
                        {
                            FullName = Users.FullName,
                            UserID = Users.Id,
                            TeamName = Teams.Name
                        };

                var Test1 = Test.ToList();
            }
        }
```

**Stacktrace**:

> Server stack trace:     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
> operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest
> request)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest
> request)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Execute(OrganizationRequest
> request)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__18(IOrganizationService
> s)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.InnerOrganizationService.UsingService[TResult](Func`2 action)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.RetrieveEntityCollection(OrganizationRequest request, NavigationSource source)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute(QueryExpression qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups,
> String& pagingCookie, Boolean& moreRecords)    at
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](QueryExpression
> qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle,
> Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)    at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> aspirets.crm.test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\a_marshall\documents\visual studio
> 2010\Projects\aspirets.crm\aspirets.crm.test\Program.cs:line 37    at
> System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
> args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
> Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> ignoreSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Instead of `Users.Id`, try `Users.SystemUserId`.

Comment: Similarly, instead of `Teams.Id`, try `Teams.TeamId`.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you very much this worked! If you post this solution as an answer rather than a comment then I'll mark the question as Accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `Users.Id`, try `Users.SystemUserId`. Similarly, instead of `Teams.Id`, try `Teams.TeamId`.

As for the reason why this works, I'm not aware of any documentation that states this, but because entities in the generated early-binding file inherit from `Entity`, they necessarily have an `Id` property. However, because the early-bound `OrganizationServiceContext` maps entity attributes directly to the CRM database, the tables of which don't contain an `Id` column, using the `Id` attribute with the LINQ provider won't work, so you'd have to use the actual database/schema names.