# Retrieve SystemUser info from TeamMembership CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to get `SystemUser` info from `TeamMembership`. I've been trying with these  snippets but the first one, create a new entity, but don't retrieve all info of the user, like email address, phone number etc...

```cs
foreach (TeamMembership user in teamMembers)
{
    sysUser.Id = user.SystemUserId.Value; 
    if (sysUser.InternalEMailAddress != string.Empty)
    {
        ActivityParty toParty = new ActivityParty();
        toParty.PartyId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, user.SystemUserId.Value);
        toPartyList.Add(toParty);
    }    
}
```

Then I've tried with this one, but it doesn't return anything!

```cs
// Get the Team Entity from the Workflow input parameter
Guid team = TeamName.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Id;
List<SystemUser> users =
    (from user in datacontext.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
     join teamMembership in datacontext.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>()
     on user.SystemUserId.Value equals teamMembership.SystemUserId
     join thisteam in datacontext.CreateQuery<Team>() on teamMembership.TeamId.Value equals thisteam.TeamId.Value
     where thisteam.Name == TeamName.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext).Name
     select user).ToList();  

foreach(SystemUser user in users)
{
    if (user.InternalEMailAddress != null)
        LoggerObj.WriteLog("User " + user.FirstName + " Email:" + user.InternalEMailAddress);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you step-by-step debug that code? Do you get any results from the query or is the problem in the foreach?

Comment: Did you see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232140/microsoft-dynamics-2011-nn-linq-query-with-where-clause-containing-guid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run your code for technical reasons (read: I'm a bit lazy) but it occurs to me that you should relax the conditions in your LINQ statement. Then, once you get in **any** *SystemUser* instance(s), you can tighten it up again. And if you don't get anything even after the full relaxation, you got an other problem. :)